# Google Maps Android API v2 custom info window example Code

Tags: android, google-maps

I already read the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) about custom info window.

but i really need the example code

where can i get that? thanks a lot

Similar to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLxfq.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's just like any adapter:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter

```
public abstract View getInfoWindow (Marker marker)
```